# How to set the owner of a file from a string variable

Tags: java, file, service, lookup, userprincipal

```
FileOwnerAttributeView FOAttr = Files.getFileAttributeView(VidFile.toPath(),FileOwnerAttributeView.class);
System.out.println(FOAttr.getOwner());
UserPrincipalLookupService lookupService = FileSystems.getDefault().getUserPrincipalLookupService();                
UserPrincipal FileOwner = lookupService.lookupPrincipalByName(UName);

System.out.println(FileOwner.getName());

FOAttr.setOwner(FileOwner);
```

What I think is a relatively simple question; I am trying to change the file's owner using the code given. It actually works pretty well up until I try to set the string variable UName to a UserPrincipal - I have included the proper import libraries but when I try to execute the code  I get  the following :

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.nio.file.attribute.UserPrincipalNotFoundException    at
>   sun.nio.fs.WindowsUserPrincipals.lookup(WindowsUserPrincipals.java:147)
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem$LookupService$1.lookupPrincipalByName(WindowsFileSystem.java:270)
>     at
>   metadataretrieval.MetadataRetrieval.main(MetadataRetrieval.java:213)
>   C:\Users\rolsen\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\debug.xml:83:
>   Java returned: 1

and now I am a bit confused... is there a trick to setting the UserPrincipal to a specific user at runtime when that user's name is in a string variable?

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.attribute.FileOwnerAttributeView;
import java.nio.file.attribute.UserPrincipalLookupService;
import java.nio.file.attribute.UserPrincipal;
```

Comment: I use the System.out.println functions to ensure I am getting proper data... I would remove these lines for the final product

Comment: Thank you for the edit... much more readable now....